# Unity - Assign Button in Scene to Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, prefab

I'm having trouble assigning two Buttons to the Prefab after it is instantiated.
The buttons are in the scene and i don't know how to assign them.
Drag and Drop doesn't work of course. I'm aware of that.
When I make something like

```
btnnext = GameObject.Find("Next").GetComponent<Button>();
```

in the Start() function of the Prefabs script it doesn't work either.

Are there any other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

As @slowikowskiarkadiusz said `GameObject.Find` is not the best solution, because it's slow and error prone. But there is an easy solution.

On the script which is placed on the prefab make a public function, called AssignButton:

```
class ScriptOnPrefab : MonoBehaviour {
   public void AssignButton(Button button) {
      btnnext = button;
   }
}
```

In the script where you instantite the prefab, you then link the buttons and assign them:

```
var instance = Instantiate(prefab);
var scriptOnPrefab = instance.GetComponent<ScriptOnPrefab>();
scriptOnPrefab.AssignButton(button);
```

**Note:** For this to work that the `ScriptOnPrefab` has to be on the root of the prefab, note on child objects.

**Note:** `prefab` is linked as a `GameObject`.

**Note:** If you link the prefab as `ScriptOnPrefab` you can skip the `GetComponent` step and immediatelly call the `Assign` method.

Answer (score -1):

By 'doesn't work either' you mean that `btnnext` is null or you mean that `.GetComponent<Button>()` throws an exception? The first case would mean the object named "Next" that was found doesn't have a Button component on it. You can check if you're expecting it to have the Button component or maybe something slightly different. You could also have multiple objects named "Next" and the one you're getting is not the one you expect to get. The second case would mean that your object is most likely inactive. `Find(string)` doesn't search within inactive objects.

That being said - `Find(string)` is not reliable in any capacity and I would advice to avoid it (it's also terribly slow). Instead I would create a script to be placed on the object with the button. Inside of that script in the `Awake()` method I would assign the instance of the Button component to some kind of a public static field, so the other script can later pick it up (if you are dealing with two buttons it might be a list or two separate fields. Depends on your case I guess).

Comment: I know it's a terrible solution... :(
there is only one Button and GameObject that is called "Next" and this Button should have a function but it does nothing when it's pressed. I can't help myself..

Comment: Oooh you want to invoke an event when clicked. There's `onClick` on the button instance. You can do `button.onClick.AddListener(()=>{<<stuff you want to be exectuted>>})` or `button.onClick.AddListener(someObject.SomeMethod)`. The second one is better because then you can call `button.onClick.RemoveListener(someObject.SomeMethod)` with the same parameter.